# fstream vector C

Tags: c, vector, ifstream

I am trying to use vector and fstream to read and store the line from a file in C. I am using Microsoft visual studio 2005. the problem is that when i compile the program, it says it could not find the file specified in include if i use .h. if i donot use .h, then it would show error in the body where i define the vector and ifstream as undeclared identifiers.

Thank you.

Comment: `vector` and `ifstream` are not part of `C`, it is part of `C++`. Are you sure your build environment is correct?

Comment: Can you post the problematic code?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the C++ classes `vector` or `fstream` in C, the C compiler cannot compile them. So you either have to change your file to .cpp (and compile it as C++), or use the C language and its methods for file handling (`fopen, fprint`...) and arrays instead of vector.

Include

```
 #include <stdio.h>
```

instead `<iostream>`

Answer (score 1):

> include if i use .h. if i donot use .h ..

I guess that you are including like -

```
#include <vector.h>
#include <ifstream.h>
```

`.h` is deprecated and should not be used for C++ headers. So, change to -

```
#include <vector>
#include <ifstream>
```

They are both are defined in std namespace. So, you should import that using `using` directive.

```
 using namespace std; // Probably missing this and is the cause for the errors
                      // vector and ifstream as undeclared identifiers.
```

Comment: @user - With your statement - `" if i donot use .h, then it would show error in the body"`, I am pretty sure that the compiler is able to find the corresponding headers. So, you are using a C++ compiler which is by default in visual studio. If it's a `C` compiler, it would have defintely bailed out at the statement `#include <vector>` but not in the body of a function. http://ideone.com/9p1Pk